# Can't get additional form fields to flow through php file

Tags: php, forms, field, addition

Hoping someone can help.  I've added some additional fields to my form, however I can't get the fields to populate within the submitted form email.  All of the standard fields work fine (email, name, comments).

Trying to get id 'bandname' and 'osflow' to work.

HTML code:

```
<div class="percent-one-half column-last box fadeInRight">
            <div id="contactform">
                <div id="message"></div>
                <form method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="cform" id="cform">
                    <fieldset class="percent-one-half">
                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name*"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="percent-one-half column-last">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="percent-one-half">
                        <input name="bandname" type="text" id="bandname" placeholder="Name of Band*"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="percent-one-half column-last">
                    <select name="interested" id="osflow" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option name="interested" value="interestedin"> Interested In </option>
                        <option name="interested" value="diecut"> Die-Cut Decal </option>
                        <option name="interested" value="static"> Static Cling Decal </option>
                        <option name="interested" value="banner"> Vinyl Banner </option>
                        <option name="interested" value="dieban"> Die-Cut Decal & Banner </option>
                        <option name="interested" value="statban"> Static Cling & Banner </option>
                    </select>
                    </fieldset>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$bandname    = $_POST['bandname'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
exit();
}


if(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
exit();
//} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
//  echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter the verification number.</div>';
//  exit();
//} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
//  echo '<div class="error_message">The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
//  exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@example.net";
$address = "info@staffordsigns.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Decal Inquiry from ' . $name . '';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name. The additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_custom = "Band Name: $bandname" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_custom2 = "Interest In: $osflow" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
$e_content .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file-7" . "\r\n";
$e_content = "Comments: $comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email at $email.";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_custom . $e_custom2 . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, we've received your inquiry and will be in touch shortly.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

There are 2 issues the php one below and your js.

in jquery.contact.js

you have:

```
$.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
```

you need to add in your 2 extra fields or they wont be posted.

**php issues:**

```
$e_custom = "Band Name: $bandname" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "\r\n";
```

you have no variable called `$bandname` but you do have `$_POST['bandname']`

notice for name,email etc you have:

```
$name     = $_POST['name'];
```

which is creating the local variables used in the email body.
While you could create a local `$bandname` variable the same way, its not necessary; you can just use the global

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I tried adding the code: $bandname    = $_POST['bandname'];     however it still doesn't seem to pull in the data from the form.  Any further tips by chance?

Comment: odd.. at the top of contact.php, add `print_r($_POST)` that will show you what values are being sent

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's still only feeding me the information from the 3 built in fields within the form template.  Array ( [name] => Test Name [email] => test@gmail.com [comments] => test message )

Comment: can i see this online anywhere?

Comment: @Promo found the problem, its in the JavaScript (jquery) - see edit in answer